# How to login in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer, headless

I'm new to JavaScript and Puppeteer.
I tried the login code below, but it failed.
In comparison, I added `page2` and succeeded.
How can I solve it?

```
const CREDS = require('./creds');

async function main() {
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 720})
  await page.goto('https://www.daum.net');
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  await page.type('#id', CREDS.username);
  await page.type('#loginPw', CREDS.password);
  await page.click('#loginSubmit');

  const page2 = await browser.newPage();
  await page2.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 720})
  await page2.goto('https://google.com');
  await page2.type('#lst-ib', 'Headless Chrome');
}

main();
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`page.waitForNavigation();` waits for navigation after a `click` or any navigation action that triggers from the page. You should probably add the `waitForNavigation()` after the `page.click()`.

```js
await Promise.all([
  page.click('#loginSubmit'),
  page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
]);
```

It will wait until both promises resolve.

So now your initial code would look like this:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function main() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width: 1200, height: 720});
  await page.goto('https://www.daum.net', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }); // wait until page load
  await page.type('#id', CREDS.username);
  await page.type('#loginPw', CREDS.password);
  // click and wait for navigation
  await Promise.all([
    page.click('#loginSubmit'),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
  ]);
}

main();
```

Note: Answer aside, I cannot test this since I don't have a login for `daum.net` and I cannot see the actual error you are facing. If you can try the solution provided above, and share the results, it'd be much more helpful.

Comment: There was an error message "Assertion failed: No node found for selector: #id" and I fixed it, your code worked beautifully!! Wow, thank you so much.

Comment: Why we need to add `{ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }` I see only `page.waitForNavigation()`, it works perfectly.

Comment: It also works with PuppeteerSharp. Thank you!

Answer (score 19):

#### page.waitForNavigation()

Logging in to a website using Puppeteer is generally as simple as using the following code:

```
await page.goto('https://www.example.com/login');

await page.type('#username', 'username');
await page.type('#password', 'password');

await page.click('#submit');

await page.waitForNavigation(); // <------------------------- Wait for Navigation

console.log('New Page URL:', page.url());
```

> **Note:** Remember to use [`page.waitForNavigation()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) after clicking the submit button to wait for the home page to display before moving forward.

Comment: how can i do if the submit button does not have and id ?

Comment: Don't `waitForNavigation` and `click` promises [need to be grouped using `Promise.all`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212395/6243352) here?

Answer (score 9):

Here's another example without an id:

```
await page.type("input[type=text]", "username");

await page.type("input[type=password]", "password");

await page.click("button[type=submit]");
```