# How to get Puppeteer waitForNavigation Working after click

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to get puppeteer to wait for the navigation to finish before moving on to the next statement. Based on the [Docs](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.7.0/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) for waitForNavigation() , the code should work below. but it just skips to the next statement and I have to use a workaround to wait for a specific URL in the response.

I have tried all the waituntil options as well
 ( load, domcontentloaded, networkidle0 and networkidle2 ) .

Any ideas how I could get that working properly is appreciated.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
})
const page = await browser.newPage()
const home = page.waitForNavigation()
await page.goto(loginUrl)
await home

const login = page.waitForNavigation()
await page.type('#email', config.get('login'))
await page.type('#password', config.get('password'))
await page.click('#submitButton')
await login // << skips over this

// the following line is my workaround and it works , but ideally I don't want 
// to specify the expected "after" page each time I navigate
await page.waitForResponse(request => request.url() === 'http://example.com/expectedurl')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to login in Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074799/how-to-login-in-puppeteer)

Comment: It could be there are no navigation at all. Maybe an example real URL or more details about the target website like framework, hash url etc might be helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The function [`page.waitForNavigation()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) waits for navigation to begin and end.

The navigation has already been initiated with [`page.click()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options).

Therefore, you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to avoid the race condition between the mentioned functions:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
});

const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto(loginUrl);

await page.type('#email', config.get('login'));
await page.type('#password', config.get('password'));

await Promise.all([
  page.click('#submitButton'),
  page.waitForNavigation({
    waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
  }),
]);

await browser.close();
```

Comment: Thanks Grant , interestingly is doesn't work! I don't know why , but it skips over. My guess is that after the logon it is finishing and then going to another page.

Comment: @MartinThompson That sounds like a possibility. You can check for redirects with [`request.redirectChain()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#requestredirectchain).

Comment: @GrantMiller I have some doubts regarding that, can we chat? It would be really helpful for me.

Comment: would be great to also show how to get the click result

Comment: @CodingYourLife check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have been going through the same problem, I used [pending-xhr-request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pending-xhr-puppeteer)

it solved many problems when the requests were expected, but when I have late requests I have faced many problems, it took me a while to solve the problem so I built a package [Puppeteer-response-waiter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-response-waiter) to do that

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const {ResponseWaiter} = require('puppeteer-response-waiter');

let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
let page = await browser.newPage();
let responseWaiter = new ResponseWaiter(page);
await page.goto('http://somesampleurl.com');
// start listening
responseWaiter.listen();
// do something here to trigger requests
await responseWaiter.wait();
// all requests are finished and responses are all returned back

// remove listeners
responseWaiter.stopListening();
await browser.close();
```

hope this will solve your problem.