# How to write Puppeteer test for Typeform?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, chromium, web-testing, puppeteer-cluster

I need test Typeform submission. But when I try to click on element it give error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded`

```
await page.waitForSelector(...)
await page.click(...)

await page.waitFor(1000);
await page.waitForNavigation();
```

You can try here: https://canyoufititcom.typeform.com/to/QXmDkX

How to fix? How I can complete form with puppeteer?

Comment: The code seems missing critical components. Please show a [mcve]. Elipses `...` make it impossible to run or to follow along with your code and provide a working, complete example in repsonse. Generally speaking, though, clicks that fire navigation must be ordered with `Promise.all([page.click(...), page.waitForNavigation()])` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211871/how-to-get-puppeteer-waitfornavigation-working-after-click).