# Puppeteer to invoke javascript function from an external .js file

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Any one has a idea on how to **invoke a javascript function** from **puppeteer** which is not inline but in an **external .js** file. If its inline within the html->head->script tag it works but not if the script tag points to an external .js file

Sample HTML File

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function inlineFunction()  {
                window.location.replace('https://www.geeksforgeeks.org');
            }
        </script>
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <p>this is an online html</p>
        <p>Link with tag a <a href="https://www.geeksforgeeks.org" name="arivalink">Href Link</a></p>
        <p>Link with inline java script - <a href="#" onClick='inlineFunction();'>Inline JS link</a></p><!-- Works -->
        <p>Link with external JS file w/o tagname - <a href="#" onClick='fileFunction();'>Ext JS Link</a></p><!-- Does not work -->
        <p>Link with external JS file w/ tagname - <a href="#" onClick='fileFunction();' name="geeksLink">Ext JS Link</a></p><!-- Does not work -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Sample Javascript file

```
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/* External Javascript File                           */
/*----------------------------------------------------*/

function fileFunction() {

    window.location.replace('https://www.geeksforgeeks.org');

}
```

Puppeteer code sample

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function start() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    //Change the path of "url" to your local path for the html file
    const url = 'file:///Users/sam.gajjar/SG/Projects/headless-chrome/sample.html'; 
    var link = '[name="link"]';

    console.log("Main URL Called");
    await page.goto(url);

    console.log("Link via HTML tag A called");
    await page.click(link);

    await page.waitForTimeout(5000) // Wait 5 seconds
        .then(() => page.goBack());
    
    console.log("Callng inline JS Function");
    await page.evaluate(() => inlineFunction());

    await page.waitForTimeout(5000) // Wait 5 seconds
        .then(() => page.goBack());

    console.log("Callng extjs file Function");
    await page.evaluate(() => fileFunction());

    await page.waitForTimeout(5000) // Wait 5 seconds
        .then(() => page.goBack());

    // console.log("Callng extjs file Function w/tag name");
    // const element = await page.$$('[a href="#"]');

    // await page.waitForTimeout(5000)
        // .then(() => page.goBack());
}

start();
```

Comment: @ggorlen - Have added the puppeteer code where the call to HTML A tag and call in inline JS function works but the same function in an external JS does not work.
The puppeteer code will call Link with HTML A then return back and call inline JS function, then return back and then call extJS function where it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `[name="link"]` should be `[name="arivalink"]` to match your DOM. I assume that's a typo.

As another aside, I recommend using the [`Promise.all` navigation pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212395/6243352) instead of `waitForTimeout` which can cause race conditions (although this doesn't appear to be related to the problem in this case).

As for the main issue, the external file is working just fine, so that's a red herring. You can prove that by calling `page.evaluate(() => fileFunction())` right after navigating to `sample.html`.

The real problem is that when you navigate with `window.location.replace('https://www.geeksforgeeks.org');`, Chromium isn't pushing that action onto the history stack. It's *replacing* the current URL, so `page.goBack()` goes back to the original `about:blank` rather than `sample.html` as you expect. `about:blank` doesn't have `fileFunction` in it, so Puppeteer throws.

Now, when you click `[name="link"]` with Puppeteer, that *does* push the history stack, so `goBack` works just fine.

You can reproduce this behavior by loading `sample.html` in a browser and navigating it by hand without Puppeteer.

Long story short, if you're calling a function in browser context using `evaluate` that runs `window.location.replace`, you can't rely on `page.goBack`. You'll need to use `page.goto` to get back to `sample.html`.

There's an interesting nuance: if you use `page.click` to invoke JS that runs `location.replace("...")`, Puppeteer *will* push the history stack and `page.goBack` will behave as expected. If you invoke the same JS logic with `page.evaluate(() => location.replace("..."));`, Puppeteer won't push the current URL to the history stack and `page.goBack` won't work as you expect. The `evaluate` behavior better aligns with "manual" browsing (i.e. as a human with a mouse and keyboard on a GUI).

Here's code to demonstrate all of this. Everything goes in the same directory and `node index.js` runs Puppeteer (I used Puppeteer 9.0.0).

#### script.js

```
const replaceLocation = () => location.replace("https://www.example.com");
const setLocation = () => location = "https://www.example.com";
```

#### sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.example.com">normal link</a> | 
    <a href="#" onclick="replaceLocation()">location.replace()</a> | 
    <a href="#" onclick="setLocation()">location = ...</a>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### index.js

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const url = "file:///Users/sam.gajjar/SG/Projects/headless-chrome/sample.html";
const log = (() => {
  let logId = 0;
  return (...args) => console.log(logId++, ...args);
})();
let browser;

(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false, 
    slowMo: 500,
  });
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url);

  // display the starting location
  log(page.url()); // 0 sample.html
  
  // click the normal link and pop the browser stack with goBack
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click("a:nth-child(1)"),
  ]);
  log(page.url()); // 1 example.com
  await page.goBack();
  log(page.url()); // 2 sample.html
  
  // fire location.replace with click
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click("a:nth-child(2)"), // pushes history (!)
  ]);
  log(page.url()); // 3 example.com
  await page.goBack();
  log(page.url()); // 4 sample.html

  // fire location.replace with evaluate
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.evaluate(() => replaceLocation()), // doesn't push history
  ]);
  log(page.url()); // 5 example.com
  await page.goBack();
  log(page.url()); // 6 about:blank <--- here's your bug!
  
  await page.goto(url); // go to sample.html from about:blank <-- here's the fix
  log(page.url()); // 7 sample.html
  
  // use location = and see that goBack takes us to sample.html
  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.evaluate(() => setLocation()), // same behavior as page.click
  ]);
  log(page.url()); // 8 example.com
  await page.goBack();
  log(page.url()); // 9 sample.html
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(async () => await browser.close())
;
```

Comment: So this works and thanks a lot for this. However I had kind of simplified the real situation by creating a sample.html and external JS file.. but this does not work for the actual case.

Am working with a 20 year old ecommerce site and here is the actual link that I have in the page. Now question.. Does it matter if there are multiple external JS and this link is in nested frameset which is 6 level deep frame?
<a href="#" onclick="create_order('','orderDealer',1); return false;">Shopping Basket</a>

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? If you open a new question, with the complete failing code, I can try to help. It's good to do a minimal example, but if the example has tainted/confusing behavior like `location.replace` borking the `goBack` logic, and that's not part of your original intent, then the example is too far from your original scenario.

Comment: Again, please open a new question and include all relevant details. All of these details like 6 layers of frames is important information that's fundamentally different than you've shown here.

Comment: Yea I would agree, but in real scenario I am don't need to use goBack() it was just in the simplfied scenario where all the links were in sample.html and wanted to show the behavior with variation of links using JS

Comment: That's fine, but it turns out that the `goBack`/`location.replace` stuff inadvertently created a bunch of new (but interesting) problems that are unrelated to the problem you're describing now. I assumed this was your real use case.

Comment: Apologies but being new to puppeteer I was not sure if it was the external JS not getting called.. v/s the actual scenario... 
Have posted a new question if it interests you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594856/puppeteer-invoke-external-js-function-from-a-6-level-deep-page-in-frameset

Comment: Appreciate if you can look at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67612278/puppeteer-invoke-external-js-function-from-a-5th-level-deep-child-page-in-fram