# Throwing an error when wating for an element to load

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

The problem is that I am trying to click on a specific option and I try to do another operation but seems that I am accessing it before the page is loaded fully after clicking on PersonalData

```
import { Page as PuppeterrPage } from "puppeteer";

export async function enterPersonalField(page: PuppeterrPage) {
  const personalFieldElement =
    "#sidebar-user-name > bb-ui-username > div > div > bdi";
  const personalData = await page.waitForSelector(personalFieldElement);

  if (personalData) {
    await personalData.click();
    // from here is the problem
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await getPersonalData(page);
  } else {
    console.log("Something broke while clicking the personal data button");
  }
}

async function getPersonalData(page) {
  await getBasicData(page);
  await getAdditinalInfo(page);
}
async function getBasicData(page) {
  const nameSelector =
    "#base-profile-full-name > bb-ui-username > div > div > bdi";
  const fullName = await page.$eval(
    nameSelector,
    (element) => element.innerText
  );
  const emailSelector = "#base-profile-email";
  console.log("Full Name:", fullName);

  const emailAddress = await page.$eval(
    emailSelector,
    (element) => element.innerText
  );

  const idSelector =
    "#body-content > div.row.collapse > div.columns.small-12.profile-content > div.columns.large-6.small-12.user-information > section:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(3) > div > a > span:nth-child(1)";
  const ID = await page.$eval(idSelector, (element) => element.innerText);
  
}
async function getAdditinalInfo(page) {
  const genderSelector =
    "#body-content > div.row.collapse > div.columns.small-12.profile-content > div.columns.large-6.small-12.user-information > section:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > div > a > span:nth-child(1) > span";
  const gender = await page.$eval(
    genderSelector,
    (element) => element.innerText
  );

  const birthSelector =
    "#body-content > div.row.collapse > div.columns.small-12.profile-content > div.columns.large-6.small-12.user-information > section:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(3) > div > a > span:nth-child(1)";
  const birthday = await page.$eval(
    birthSelector,
    (element) => element.innerText
  );
  console.log("Birthday: ", birthday);

  const eduLevelSelector =
    "#body-content > div.row.collapse > div.columns.small-12.profile-content > div.columns.large-6.small-12.user-information > section:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(4) > div > a > span:nth-child(1) > span";
  const eduLevelInfo = await page.$eval(
    eduLevelSelector,
    (element) => element.innerText
  );
  console.log("Education level: ", eduLevelInfo);
}
```

when I run this, it gives me this error:    throw new Error(`Error: failed to find element matching selector "${selector}"`);
^

I tried to add a waiter for an element to load but I don't want that because it is not always going to wait for a specific amount of time

Comment: You're waiting for navigation after triggering the click. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212395/6243352) for the correct format (although waiting for an element on the next page is probably better than waiting for a navigation in any case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only solutions are:

1. Wait until an element is visible:

```
if (personalData) {
    await personalData.click();
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    
    const nameSelector = "#base-profile-full-name > bb-ui-username > div > div > bdi";
    await page.waitForSelector(nameSelector, { visible: true });
    
    await getPersonalData(page);
  } else {
    console.log("Something broke while clicking the personal data button");
  }
}
```

2. Insert a timeout:

```
if (personalData) {
    await personalData.click();
    await page.waitForNavigation();

    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000)); // 5 Seconds

    await getPersonalData(page);
  } else {
    console.log("Something broke while clicking the personal data button");
  }
}
```

Comment: I used both along with each other but still the same problem. The user's browser may take more time or less time to load so I was hoping to find a way to wait until the page is fully loaded, but it seems there isn't

Comment: Try this:


await page.waitForNavigation({
  waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
});

Comment: did it but after loading the page fully it stops and doesn't do anything after it