# Puppeteer selector cannot find the correct element into the iframe

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to make work a selector to click on the 'search' button, I have already typed in the input but still without success to click on the 'search' button, it should be noted that the form is inside a iframe.

Here is my code

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
const url = "https://www.mercadopublico.cl/Home";

async function openWebPage() {
  puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    timeout: 70000,
    headless: false,
    executablePath: "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe",
    userDataDir: "C:/Users/javsiv7/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data",
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url, { timeout: 70000 });
  await page.waitForSelector('button.btn.btn-xl.btn-pri', { timeout: 70000 });
  await page.click('button.btn.btn-xl.btn-pri', { timeout: 70000 });
  await page.waitForSelector('#zocial-oidc', { timeout: 70000 });
  await page.click('#zocial-oidc', {timeout :70000 });
  
  // write username and password
  await page.waitForSelector("#uname", { timeout: 70000 });
  await page.type("#uname", "27.063.931-3");
  await page.waitForSelector("#pword", { timeout: 70000 });
  await page.type("#pword", "Meryi.15");
  // click login
  await page.waitForSelector("#login-submit", { timeout: 70000 });
  await page.click("#login-submit");
  await page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 70000});
  await page.waitForSelector('#rdbOrg1820428', { timeout: 70000 });
  await page.click('#rdbOrg1820428');
  await page.waitForSelector('a.btn.btn-pri', { timeout: 70000 });
  await page.click('a.btn.btn-pri', {timeout: 70000});
  await page.waitForNavigation({timeout: 70000});
  await page.click('#mnuPrincipaln3 .mnuPrincipal_1', {timeout: 70000});
  const elementHandle = await page.waitForSelector('#fraDetalle');
  const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
  await frame.waitForSelector('.MuiInputBase-input', { timeout: 70000 });
  await frame.type('.MuiInputBase-input', '900-127-COT24');
  await frame.waitForSelector('button.MuiButtonBase-root.Buttonstyles__BaseButton-sc-1r23i1a-2.Buttonstyles__ContainedButton-sc-1r23i1a-3.exhqeh.ktEJEN.QuoteSearchHeadingFiltersstyles__SearchButton-sc-475dvi-1.bPKlqW[color="primary"][type="submit"]', { timeout: 70000, visible: true });
  await frame.click('button.MuiButtonBase-root.Buttonstyles__BaseButton-sc-1r23i1a-2.Buttonstyles__ContainedButton-sc-1r23i1a-3.exhqeh.ktEJEN.QuoteSearchHeadingFiltersstyles__SearchButton-sc-475dvi-1.bPKlqW[color="primary"][type="submit"]');
}

openWebPage();
```

exactly on this line of code is where it stops working:

```
await frame.click('button.MuiButtonBase-root.Buttonstyles__BaseButton-sc-1r23i1a-2.Buttonstyles__ContainedButton-sc-1r23i1a-3.exhqeh.ktEJEN.QuoteSearchHeadingFiltersstyles__SearchButton-sc-475dvi-1.bPKlqW[color="primary"][type="submit"]');
```

Comment: Instead of `{timeout: 70000}` on every call you can use `setDefaultTimeout`. Also, your clicks that trigger a nav have race conditions. Use [this pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52211871/how-to-get-puppeteer-waitfornavigation-working-after-click/52212395#52212395), or wait for a selector on the next page rather than waiting for navigation. You might want to read through [this blog post](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#never-using-domcontentloaded) of mine--there are a lot of other little tips you can use, like the fact that `waitForSelector` returns the element.

Comment: Your credentials are here in plain text.

Comment: `#mnuPrincipaln3 .mnuPrincipal_1` is in an iframe, so you'll need to drill into the frame first. Does [How to select elements within an iframe element in Puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56420047/how-to-select-elements-within-an-iframe-element-in-puppeteer/56420104#56420104) answer your question? I don't see `.MuiInputBase-input` anywhere in the document though, so I'm not sure which element that should refer to offhand.

Comment: '.MuiInputBase-input' is the selector that should allow typing in the input, but actually testing I can't get any selector to work either to click a button or other things, what do you mean with the inframe, does it not allow to take any selector?

Comment: Please read the link--you need to select the `<iframe>` first and query within it. I don't see `.MuiInputBase-input` anywhere so I'm not sure what you're trying to click.

Comment: I understand, I will try with what you say and tell you, when I say to click it was trying with other selectors but the attempts were in vain, I will read the article and tell you the results.

Comment: I have been able to type in the input, thank you very much for the guidance, one more question, I need to click on the search button, I can't do it, my question is the following, do I have to select the iframe again or is the previous one enough?

Comment: No problem, glad things are moving forward. Can you update the code here to show your latest problem? Once you store the iframe in a variable, you should be able to reuse it as a drop-in for `page`.

Comment: hello how have you been, so far this is what I have updated to the code, as I said before I managed to type in the input, now I want to click on the 'Search' button but I can not get it yet, try the selector in the browser console and if it works, but in the code is up to where I type in the input.

Comment: The code still seems the same as before. I don't see any iframe code was added.

Comment: ready, code updated below

Comment: This should be an [edit] to your original post, not an answer. When you edit, please update the text of the question and its title to correspond to the new problem.

Comment: I already corrected it

Comment: Ask yourself why you have all these timeouts, because this makes no sense. Either elements are on the page, or they're not on the page, or they're "not yet" on the page, but it can't possibly be the case that _every_ element you're querying may take _another_ 70 seconds to get put on the page. By having these _incredibly_ long  timeouts, you're just hiding the actual thing that's probably wrong by having your queries take forever to actually fail.

Comment: And of course as step zero: load the URL in your own browser. Because the page you're trying to load _is broken_ thanks to it violating CORS restrictions.

Comment: The excessive time is because I was closed by timeout, that's how it has worked for me, and what do you mean specifically with my own browser? so far the modification of the code has gone well, only that I can not click the search button.