# Pressing Escape manually dismisses a prompt outside the DOM but if done through Puppeteer it has no effect. Why & how to allow it to have an effect?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

When I manually sign into Slack through the browser I'm able to hit the escape key to make the Chrome prompt which is outside the DOM go away. But when using Puppeteer programmatically hitting the escape key via `page.keyboard.press('Escape')` has zero effect. I'm wondering if I'm not thinking of something else that needs to happen in order for the press to register.

Going through SO I do see others with similar issues. And since these prompts are outside the DOM the consensus is that there's really nothing Puppeteer can do. But seeing how I'm able to hit the escape key to make the prompt go away I'm wondering if there is something there.

```js
export const runPuppeteer = async () => {
  // Launch the browser and open a new blank page
    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();

      // Navigate the page to a URL
      await page.goto('https://tonkotsu-ramen.slack.com/sign_in_with_password');

      // Set screen size
      await page.setViewport({ width: 1080, height: 1024 });

      // Type into search box
      await page.type('#email', process.env.SLACK_USER_EMAIL);
      await page.type('#password', process.env.SLACK_USER_PASSWORD);

      // Click on sign in button
      await page.click('#signin_btn');

      // Wait for sign in to finish
      await page.waitForNavigation();

      // Close the browser prompt
      await page.keyboard.press('Escape');

      // Wait for link to load onto page
      await page.waitForSelector('::-p-text(use Slack in your browser)'); 

      await page.goto('https://tonkotsu-ramen.slack.com');

      browser.close();
  })()
};
```

[image]

Comment: Not related to your issue, but `await page.waitForNavigation();` and your click [have a race condition](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#not-using-promiseall-when-triggering-navigation-with-a-click). I would `await browser.close();`, or better yet, move it to a `finally` block so it'll run even if the code throws.

Comment: I see what you're saying regarding the race condition as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212395/8378893). And thanks for the suggestion about including `finally`.