# Cannot find context with specified id in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

i have a page with cards i click on the title of each it takes to a page then i click on a link in that page and it takes me another page to extract the data that i want. After that i navigate back twice to go back to the main page and scrape the rest of the cards but iam getting this error
Error occurred while processing card: ProtocolError: Protocol error (DOM.describeNode): Cannot find context with specified id

```
const categoriesArray = require('./categories');

function formatCategoryString(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
}

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); // Launch in non-headless mode
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://www.discudemy.com/all');
    console.log('Scraping started');

    await page.waitForSelector('body > article section.card');

    const cardsContainer = await page.$$('body > article section.card');
    console.log(`Number of card elements found: ${cardsContainer.length}`);

    for (const card of cardsContainer) {
      try {
        const categoryElement = await card.$(
          '.extra.content .right.floated.author a .catSpan'
        );
        if (!categoryElement) {
          console.log('Category element not found within card');
          continue;
        }

        const category = await (
          await categoryElement.getProperty('innerText')
        ).jsonValue();
        const formattedCategory = formatCategoryString(category);

        if (categoriesArray.includes(formattedCategory)) {
          const titleElement = await card.$('.content .header a');
          const title = await (
            await titleElement.getProperty('innerText')
          ).jsonValue();

          const descriptionElement = await card.$('.content .description');
          const description = await (
            await descriptionElement.getProperty('innerText')
          ).jsonValue();

          const imageElement = await card.$('.image img');
          const imageURL = await (
            await imageElement.getProperty('src')
          ).jsonValue();

          const priceElement = await card.$('.meta span:last-child');
          const price = await (
            await priceElement.getProperty('innerText')
          ).jsonValue();

          titleElement.click();
          await page.waitForNavigation();

          const couponPageLink = await page.$('div a.ui.green.discBtn');
          if (couponPageLink) {
            await couponPageLink.click();
            await page.waitForNavigation();
          }

          const couponLink = await page.$('.ui.segment a');
          const hrefValue = await page.evaluate(
            (element) => element.getAttribute('href'),
            couponLink
          );

          console.log('Title:', title);
          console.log('Description:', description);
          console.log('Image URL:', imageURL);
          console.log('Price:', price);
          console.log('Category:', category);
          console.log('Link: ', hrefValue);
          await Promise.all([await page.goBack(), await page.goBack()]);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error occurred while processing card:', error);
        continue;
      }
    }

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

A few remarks:

1. When scraping, there's no need to behave like the user would (clicking things, working through the pages in a certain order, using 'back' buttons). It's often [better to use `goto` to navigate between pages](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/06/14/puppeteer-in-nodejs-more-antipatterns-to-avoid.html#adding-premature-abstractions#underusing-pagegoto). `waitForNavigation()` causes race conditions when [not set before a click action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52212395/6243352), but using `goto` avoids this since it waits for navigation automatically.

   I haven't tested it, but `Promise.all()` on multiple `goBack()` calls looks risky since they may interleave and cause problems. Some pages hijack the back button, so I don't generally use this.
2. When navigating back to a previous page, you need to re-query elements, because the handles from a previous load are no longer valid and will throw if you try to use them.

   A workaround is to keep the main page open on the home site, and pop open new pages for drilling into each sub-link.

   Even better: you're under no obligation to visit the pages in any order, so you could scrape all of the data you need from the main page up front, then visit all of the sub-links from the scraped URLs without needing to return to the main page to find the next item.
3. Avoid element handles whenever possible. They're slow (involving multiple network trips), unreliable (can go stale) and annoying to code with (extra promises to drill down to a primitive value). Prefer `$eval` or `$$eval` and scrape your data using simple, synchronous browser code.
4. [Await all promises](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#forgetting-to-await-a-puppeteer-call) to avoid race conditions. `titleElement.click();` wasn't awaited. The only exception are occasional cases where you intentionally want interleaving and there's no dependency between the actions that might cause an error.
5. If the page doesn't require JS, disable it. If you don't need stylesheets and images, it's a waste to pull them down, both for you and the server. [Block them](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#not-blocking-images-and-resources).

Putting it together:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.2.0

const url = "<Your URL>";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", req => {
    if (req.resourceType() === "document") {
      req.continue();
    } else {
      req.abort();
    }
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const data = await page.$$eval(
    "body > article section.card",
    els =>
      els
        .map(e => {
          const text = s =>
            e.querySelector(s)?.textContent.trim();
          return {
            title: text(".content .header a"),
            url: e.querySelector(".content .header a")?.href,
            description: text(".content .description"),
            imageURL: e
              .querySelector(".image amp-img")
              ?.getAttribute("src"),
            price: text(".meta span:last-child"),
            category: text(".extra.content .catSpan"),
          };
        })
        .filter(e => e.url)
  );

  for (const e of data) {
    await page.goto(e.url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    const href = await page.$eval(
      "::-p-text(Take Course)",
      el => el.href
    );
    await page.goto(href, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    e.hrefValue = await page.$eval(
      "div::-p-text(Course Coupon)",
      e => e.parentElement.querySelector("a").href
    );
  }

  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

That said, now that we're disabling JS and blocking all requests except plain text documents, we [probably don't need Puppeteer at all](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-puppeteer-when-other-tools-are-more-appropriate). Consider re-writing this with fetch and cheerio, which should be faster and easier (less async code).

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";

const get = url =>
  fetch(url).then(res => {
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Error(res.statusText);
    }

    return res.text();
  });

(async () => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(await get(url));
  const data = [...$("body > article section.card")]
    .map(e => {
      const text = s => $(e).find(s).text().trim();
      return {
        title: text(".content .header a"),
        url: $(e).find(".content .header a")?.attr("href"),
        description: text(".content .description"),
        imageURL: $(e).find(".image amp-img")?.attr("src"),
        price: text(".meta span:last-child"),
        category: text(".extra.content .catSpan"),
      };
    })
    .filter(e => e.url);

  for (const e of data) {
    const $1 = cheerio.load(await get(e.url));
    const href = $1(".discBtn").attr("href");
    const $2 = cheerio.load(await get(href));
    e.hrefValue = $2(
      "[href^='https://www.udemy.com/course/']"
    ).attr("href");
  }

  console.log(data);
})();
```

Puppeteer:

```
real 0m8.535s
user 0m2.516s
sys  0m0.594s
```

Cheerio:

```
real 0m7.023s
user 0m0.828s
sys  0m0.073s
```

You can also parallelize some of the URL requests, depending on how gentle you want to be on the server, and left as an exercise.

<sub>Disclosure: I'm the author of the linked blog posts.</sub>