# Puppeteer webscraper not letting me use page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape data from a website using the Puppeteer webscraping API on NodeJS, but I keep running into a problem. I want to take data from a row, navigate into that row (each row acts as a link), navigate back out again, and then move onto the next row, something like this:

```
const projects = await page.$$(
  "#tenderListFEBean > div > section > div.table-root > table > tbody.list-tbody > tr"
);

for (const project of projects) {
  const projectName = `${(await page.evaluate((el) => el.querySelector("td.col_TITLE.tdMedium > a.detailLink").textContent,project)).trim()}`;

  await Promise.all([
    page.click(`tr > td.col_TITLE.tdMedium > a`),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" }),
  ]);

  //I navigate a bit more and take some data

  await Promise.all([
    page.click(
      "span.SvgSize16.SVG-arrow-left.ICON-MAINBACK.js_svg.IconButton-label",
    ),
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: "networkidle0" }),
  ]);
}
```

But everytime I do, it works the first time round, but when it navigates back out of first row and tries to take the projectName of the second, I get this error:

```
ProtocolError: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Argument should belong to the same JavaScript world as target object
```

I'm imagining this is something to do with the "project" argument being created before I did the navigation into the first row, so not being in the same 'world' as the selector its trying to query, but I have no idea how to fix it...

Comment: Your guess about the cause is correct--those handles are stale and need to be re-queried. Can you share the site? It's hard to provide a working answer otherwise, and there's almost certainly a more straightforward way to achieve this. Prefer `goto` to clicks and avoid element handles. Also watch out for [long, ultra-rigid selector chains](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors) which are liable to break if a single assumption changes in the target page.

Comment: See [Cannot find context with specified id in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78121820/cannot-find-context-with-specified-id-in-puppeteer/78123949#78123949) which has the same pattern as this and offers a few solutions. Please also share the rest of your code as a [mcve]. The solution depends on what happens in `// I navigate a bit more...`--I want to move the `projectName` loop out to a preliminary loop, but if there's navigation back to the first page in the main loop, that won't be enough. Thanks.