# Protocol error (DOM.describeNode): Could not find object with given id

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape a tech news website. I want to get all the updated news on the first home page. When I click on the first blog image to navigate to next page, it opens that page, but is unable to scrape it. My selectors are all correct. I have been searching for the past 2 hours and I am unable to find the solution. Some websites have ticked being closed because no one answered.

````js
import puppeteer from "puppeteer-extra";
import StealthPlugin from "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth";
import scroller from "./Helper/scroller.js";

// Add stealth plugin and use defaults (all evasion techniques)
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  console.log("Running tests..");
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://thenextweb.com/");
  await page.waitForSelector(".o-wrapper");

  try {
    await page.waitForSelector(
      ".cookie-consent-banner__btn-primary.c-button.c-button--primary"
    );
    await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 3000));
    await page.click(
      ".cookie-consent-banner__btn-primary.c-button.c-button--primary"
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error occurred while handling cookie consent:", error);
  }

  `plz help```
  await page.waitForSelector(".o-grid__col");
  await scroller(page);

  const cardElements = await page.$$(
    ".o-grid__col.md\\:o-grid__col--1\\/2.lg\\:o-grid__col--1\\/4"
  );
  const dataStoringArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < cardElements.length; i++) {
    const cardElement = cardElements[i];
    const imgElement = await cardElement.$(".o-media");
    await imgElement.click();
    // await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.waitForSelector(".o-wrapper");

    // Now scrape this page
    const scrapedData = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const titleElement = document.querySelector(".c-header__heading").textContent;
    

      return { titleElement };
    });
    dataStoringArray.push(scrapedData);

    await page.goBack();
    await page.waitForSelector(".o-grid__col");
  }

  console.log(dataStoringArray);
  await browser.close();
})();
````

Comment: Once you trigger a nav, all of the element handles from the previous page go stale. You need to re-query them, or collect all URLs once, then loop over them and use `goto` on each one to navigate to the sub-pages. I suggest avoiding `goBack()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78121820/cannot-find-context-with-specified-id-in-puppeteer/78123949#78123949). Also, try to [avoid timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352). I'll add an answer if you can't figure it out based on the linked post.