# Unable to retrieve element by id on archive.org

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

https://archive.org/search?query=shakespeare

On the left side of archive.org pages there is always a results count.

This in inspect shows

```html
<div id="results-total">
  <span id="big-results-count">
    <!--?lit$0841345236$-->51,018
  </span>
  <span id="big-results-label">
    <!--?lit$0841345236$-->Results
  </span>
</div>
```

But this always fails:

```js
const resCountDivVal = await page.$eval(
  '#big-results-count',
  element => element.textContent
);
```

Groovy also fails:

```
webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("big-results-count")))
```

All of chatgpt suggestions:

```js
await page.waitForNavigation();
await page.waitForSelector('#big-results-count');
```

I tried a diff script in which every id and class is listed. For every archive.org URL it failed, for others it worked.

I also noticed page source is not the HTML equivalent of what you see upon inspect. It is merely some textual info.

How can I get the big-results-count?

```js
async function setArchiveItemCountAndScrollablePageCount() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: "new"});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

    await page.goto(MAIN_URL);

    console.log(`MAIN_URL page.goto ${MAIN_URL}`);
    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.waitForSelector('#big-results-count');
    const resultsCount = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const element = document.querySelector('#big-results-count');
      return element ? element.textContent : null;
    });
    console.log(`resultsCount ${resultsCount}`);

    //big-results-count
    //results_count
    const resCountDivVal = await page.$eval('#big-results-count', element => element.textContent);
    archiveItemCount = parseInt(resCountDivVal?.trim().split(/\s.*/g)[0].replace(",", "")) || 0;
    await browser.close();
    console.log(`resCount ${archiveItemCount}`);
    setScrollablePageCount();
    return archiveItemCount;
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error in setArchiveItemCountAndScrollablePageCount ${err}`);
    return 0;
  }
}
```

This function just times out and fails.

Comment: Why not use the [archive.org API](https://archive.org/developers/)? In any case, that element is in a shadow root. See [Puppeteer not giving accurate HTML code for page with shadow roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68525115/puppeteer-not-giving-accurate-html-code-for-page-with-shadow-roots/68540701#68540701) and [Can't locate and click on a terms of conditions button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74057130/cant-locate-and-click-on-a-terms-of-conditions-button/74057427#74057427)

Comment: Avoid [timeout: 0](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#using-infinite-timeouts) and [spurious `waitForNavigation()` calls](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#making-unnecessary-calls-to-waitfornetworkidle-or-waitfornavigation).

Comment: Dear ggorlen so yes now everything is working. 

this did the trick 

  await page.goto(MAIN_URL, {
      waitUntil: "networkidle0"
    });

    const resultsCount = await page.$$eval(
      ">>> span#big-results-count",
      els => els.map(e => e.textContent.trim())
    );